# May there be an indefenite article after a definite?

Tags: articles

May there be such order of articles: `...in the end of a...`? Definite end of something indefinite.

*What about the opposite by the way (`a/an`, then `the`)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, certainly.

In the same way that once we have introduced a new entity by *a*, and then refer to that entity by *the* thereafter:

> I bought **a** book this morning. After lunch I picked **the** book up and read it.

we can refer to attributes or relations of the new entity by *the* even in the same phrase where it is introduced:

> **The** title page of **a** book I bought had been scribbled on.

(Note that this example does not follow the previous example and refer to the same book: it would say ***the** book* if it did).

**Edit**: In fact, unless the book has multiple title pages, it has to be ***the** title page*. You could say *a page of a book*, because a book normally has many pages, but when you are referring to something unique in the book, or all of something, it has to be *the*. So *an author of a book I bought* implies that the book had several authors, but *the author of a book I bought* implies that it had only one author. Similarly, *the covers of a book I bought*, *the subject of a book I bought*, but *a story in a book I bought* if the book contained more than one story.

The other way round is also fine, when the meaning justifies it:

> I was looking at **a** picture in **the** book I bought this morning.

The picture is newly introduced into the conversation, while the book has probably already been mentioned.

Comment: If title of a book is newly introduced then it shouldn't be `the`, right? Only if it was mentioned before?

Comment: No. You could say _a page of a book_, but since a book normally has only one title, it would be _the title of a book_. Actually, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: in the end of an x, you accept that? What you said the other day to me, applies here to you. :)

Comment: I accept it if the x is qualified somehow. _In the end of a film I saw last year_ is fine. It's odd without that qualifier, though I don't think it's imposssible, with context.